# Regex find instance of dash, but not <space>dash<space>

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am sooo close. I am trying code a regex expression for Notepad++ to replace a dash with a space, *ignoring* dashes already with a pre/post space. I realize I could search/replace " - " with "foobarfoo" then search for "-" replacing for " " then converting "foobarfoo" back to " - ", but damnit - I'm trying to learn regex!

Here's my problem:

> Adapter - BNC Male to BNC-Female, Right Angle

to

> Adapter - BNC Male to BNC Female, Right Angle

(note the disappearing dash in "BNC Female")

The closest I am getting is using this:
`/(?:[^( )])\-(?:[^( )])/g`

but that results with it finding the single letter ahead, the dash, and the single letter following:

> Adapter - BNC Male to BN**C-F**emale, Right Angle

WHY is it selecting the pre/post characters? Is this not:

`(?:[^( )])`  find anything except a space (as a noncapturing group)...

`\-`      ... that follows with a dash ...

`(?:[^( )])`  ... and is followed by anything except a space(as a noncapturing group)

I get even closer is I replace the first term with `(?=[^( )])` but if I change the third term to `(?![^( )])` I'm back to where I started - just selecting the dash in between the two spaces. GRRRR.

More samples here at http://regexr.com/444i2

Comment: Have you tried [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): [`\b-\b`](https://regex101.com/r/a8YoOH/2)

Comment: Your question assumes you only want to avoid matching `<space>-<space>`, but it seems you want to avoid `<space>-` and `-<space>`, too. Is it true?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To ignore dashes already with a pre/post space you could use positive [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that what is on the left and on the right are a non whitespace character `\S`

In the replacement use a space.

`(?<=\S)-(?=\S)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NsRljK/1)

Comment: Ahh... whitespace flag. Thanks for that education. Does the trick!

Answer (score 2):

The most readable option for Notepad++ is an alternation based regex with a conditional replacement pattern:

**Find What**: `(\s-\s)|-`
**Replace With**: `(?1$1: )`

The `(\s-\s)|-` pattern either captures into Group 1 a whitespace, `-` and a whitespace, or just matches `-`. If Group 1 matches, its value is pasted back where it was (=this match is skipped), else the `-` in other contexts is replaced with a space.

See a demo below:
[image]

Another option is using nested lookarounds:

**Find What**: `-(?<!\s-(?!=\s))`
**Replace With**:   (a space)

The pattern matches:

- `-` - a hyphen
- `(?<!\s-(?!=\s))` - this negative lookbehind fails the match if its pattern matches the following pattern immediately to the left of the current location (that is, right after `-`):

  - `\s` - a whitespace
  - `-` - a hyphen (this is necessary to make sure we get to the same place where the lookbehind was triggered)
  - `(?!=\s)` - the next char is a whitespace (this is a lookahead, it is not possible to make it a simple `\s` as we cannot let the lookbehind move its pattern position matching, i.e. we can't let it try `\s-\s` before and including `-` (it would result in a *true* result).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\w(-)\w` to replace all hyphens surrounded by alphabetic characters, digits and underscores, or `[^ ](-)[^ ]` to replace all hyphens surrounded by non-space characters.

Both work fine in my Notepad++ version with all of your examples.